# If I upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04, and then to 13.10 and so... Will I have any problem?

Tags: upgrade, versions

If I upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04, and then to 13.10 and so... Will I have any problem? Greetings from Argentina.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update some of your applications, too, as well as most PPAs you've installed, but in general you should not run into problems.  I followed such a sequence myself and found that it worked quite well.  (In fact, one of my systems has been updated with each new Ubuntu release starting with 11.04, and it is very solid and reliable.)

Of course, as with any such endeavor, you should make sure your system is backed-up.

Buena suerte.  Yo era misionero en la Argentina durante los setenta, y todavia amo al pais.